# How to highlight select row in rstudio dataframe view()?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have read [how to use data viewer](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205175388-Using-the-Data-Viewer)

But how to highlight select row in rstudio?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `formattable`, it will highlight the row:

```
data=data("iris")
library(formattable)
iris %>% 
    head(5e2) %>% 
    formattable() %>% 
    as.datatable
```